# Combinar arquivo .shp com um data frame

Tags: r

Li um arquivo .shp com o pacote `sf`.

```
map_recife = st_read("./shape/Bairros.shp", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

> glimpse(map_recife)
Observations: 94
Variables: 11
$ CBAIRRCODI <dbl> 19, 27, 35, 43, 51, 60, 78, 86, 94, 108, 116, 124,...
$ VBAIRROID  <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,...
$ EBAIRRNOME <chr> "RECIFE", "SANTO ANTONIO", "SAO JOSE", "ILHA JOANA...
$ CRPAAACODI <dbl> 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2,...
$ CMICROCODI <dbl> 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,...
$ TBAIRRULAT <date> 1899-12-30, 1899-12-30, 1899-12-30, 1899-12-30, 1...
$ CEMPRECODI <int> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,...
$ AUSUACMATR <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,...
$ EBAIRRNO_1 <chr> "Recife", "Santo Antônio", "São José", "Ilha Joana...
$ EBAIRRLINK <chr> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA...
$ geometry   <MULTIPOLYGON [m]> MULTIPOLYGON (((294617.4 91..., MULTI...
```

E tenho outro `dataFrame`, `chamado`:

```
> chamado

# A tibble: 40,211 x 3
     lat   lon classe      
   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>       
 1 -7.99 -34.9 Deslizamento
 2 -8.11 -34.9 Deslizamento
 3 -8.13 -35.0 Deslizamento
 4 -8.12 -34.9 Outros      
 5 -8.00 -34.9 Deslizamento
 6 -8.01 -34.9 Deslizamento
 7 -8.13 -34.9 Outros      
 8 -8.00 -34.9 Deslizamento
 9 -8.06 -34.9 Outros      
10 -8.05 -34.9 Outros      
# ... with 40,201 more rows
```

Gostaria de adicionar em `map_recife` uma nova informação que contasse quantos `deslizamentos`, `inundações` ou `outros` ocorreram para cada bairro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa de uma agregação por localização espacial. O pacote sf tem a função `st_join` para isso.

Como não tenho seus dados estou usando um shapefile dos distritos da cidade de São Paulo que já possuo e sorteando aleatoriamente 1000 pontos sobre eles. O link para o shapefile e o código para gerar o exemplo estão no final da resposta.

```
library(sf)
library(sp) # para converter o data.frame com pontos para objeto espacial

poligonos <- st_read('~/Shapefiles/SaoPaulo/DISTRITOS.shp')

> head(pontos)
        classe      lon     lat
1        Outro 357187.1 7393834
2 Deslizamento 321756.3 7367707
3 Deslizamento 335457.6 7351122
4        Outro 322111.1 7371642
5    Inundação 319832.9 7356027
6    Inundação 334791.4 7356819

coordinates(pontos) <- ~lon+lat  # converte para objeto espacial

uniao <- st_join(st_as_sf(pontos), poligonos)

tabela <- table(uniao$NOME_DISTR, uniao$classe)    

> head(tabela)

                    Deslizamento Inundação Outro
  AGUA RASA                    1         2     0
  ALTO DE PINHEIROS            1         4     1
  ANHANGUERA                  12         2    12
  ARICANDUVA                   2         2     0
  ARTUR ALVIM                  2         2     0
  BARRA FUNDA                  1         2     0
```

## Código para o exemplo

```
library(rgdal)
library(sp)

poligonos <- readOGR('~/Shapefiles/SaoPaulo', 'DISTRITOS')
# http://dados.prefeitura.sp.gov.br/dataset/distritos    

set.seed(1234)
pontos <- spsample(poligonos, 1000, 'random')  # sorteia pontos
pontos$classe <- sample(c('Deslizamento', 'Inundação', 'Outro'), 1000, replace = TRUE)

plot(poligonos)
plot(subset(pontos, classe == 'Inundação'), col = 'blue', add = T)
plot(subset(pontos, classe == 'Deslizamento'), col = 'darkgreen', add = T)
plot(subset(pontos, classe == 'Outro'), col = 'gray40', add = T)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
# para seguir o mesmo formato dos seus dados:
pontos <- as.data.frame(pontos)
names(pontos)[2:3] <- c('lon', 'lat')
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, Carlos. Era o que precisava!